# Error: $interpolate:noconcat Multiple Expressions

Tags: angularjs, templates, iframe

Is it possible to add links with iframe with src parameters in `ul` lists generated by the API?

URL concentration really. I have API delivering data and I wish to show it as a list with iframes.

I have this code template:

```
(...)
var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
var  template = '<ul>'
            +'<li ng-repeat="li in item.list" class="[[li.class]]">'
            +'<iframe width="100%" height="300"'
            +'ng-src="https://myserver.com/?id=[[li.mydata]]"'
            +'</iframe>'
            +'</li></ul>';
        return template;
    };
(...)
```

interpolate is set to `[[` and `]]`

SCE secure is trusted

```
.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
    'self',
    'https://myserver.com/**',
  ])
 })
```

When adding to template `<h4>[[li.mydata]]</h4>` result is visible, but when to iframe ng-src - fails with this error

`https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$interpolate/noconcat?p0=`

Any idea or suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed a problem with

```
(...)
            +'<iframe width="100%" height="300"'
            +'ng-src="[[li.mydata | EmbedUrl ]]"'
(...)
```

Then into ng.js

```
  .filter('EmbedUrl', function ($sce) {
  return function(uId) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('https://example.com/?id=' + uId  );
  };
```